# OpenOCD debugging issue with st link

Tags: cortex-m, openocd

I purchased STM32F69 discovery board and installed Eclipse with MCU plugin for C/C++ development and also OpenOCD. While experimenting with some sample code, debugging stops at the only breakpoint I setup. I decided to watch two expressions - structure TIM2 and the other one TIM2->CNT. At the breakpoint, I saw different numbers when rolling out TIM2 value (to watch CNT) compared to second expression TIM2->CNT. Moreover, when looking at memory (0x40000000 for TIM2), I noticed some third value.
What could be explanation for such behavior ?

Comment: F69, is that missing a number? Does CubeIDE work - it's after all just an Eclipse but packaged and configured by the vendor.

Comment: You are right, I missed the number - it is STM32F769. I don't have CubeIDE installed, because my first intention was not to work with STM controllers. If I don't find some reasonable explanation, I certainly will.

Comment: Although the issue I described is not the only "weird" one, after few tests, I realized  that I probably misunderstood the behavior of timer while program reaches breakpoint. I thought that it simply stops running, however it seems that the truth is opposite. Hence distinct values of CNT at different watches while being at breakpoint.